# Default parameter values in SQL Server 2008 stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I feel like an idiot, but I can't make this SP default a value.... Here's how I'm declaring my parameters.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PCS_DocumentCacheInsert]
(
    @sessionId varchar(200),
    @mrn varchar(50) ,
    @fromDate datetime,
    @toDate datetime,
    @aggregate varchar(50),
    @author varchar(50),
    @datePerformed dateTime,
    @docId varchar(15),
    @encounterId varchar(15),
    @facility varchar(5),
    @level char(1),
    @orderedByAuthor varchar(50),
    @resultAuthor varchar(50),
    @resultCode varchar(5),
    @resultId varchar(30),
    @resultName varchar(30),
    @status varchar(5),
    @subType varchar(10),
    @type varchar(10),
    @security varchar(3),
    @serviceGroup varchar(15),
    @witmurNum varchar(10),
    @deptId varchar(10),
    @deptText varchar(40),
    @cacheCreateTS dateTime ,
    @cacheStatus varchar(8) ='notReady',
    @cacheUpdateTS datetime
)
```

Everything works fine with this proc except I can't get `notReady` to default for `@cacheStatus`.  Google says I'm using the correct syntax.

here is how i call in MS

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[PCS_DocumentCacheInsert]
    @sessionId = N'asdfssa',
    @mrn = N'asdf',
    @fromDate = NULL,
    @toDate = NULL,
    @aggregate = NULL,
    @author = N'author',
    @datePerformed = NULL,
    @docId = N'id',
    @encounterId = NULL,
    @facility = NULL,
    @level = NULL,
    @orderedByAuthor = NULL,
    @resultAuthor = NULL,
    @resultCode = NULL,
    @resultId = NULL,
    @resultName = NULL,
    @status = NULL,
    @subType = NULL,
    @type = NULL,
    @security = NULL,
    @serviceGroup = NULL,
    @witmurNum = NULL,
    @deptId = NULL,
    @deptText = NULL,
    @cacheCreateTS = NULL,
    @cacheStatus = NULL,
    @cacheUpdateTS = NULL
```

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO

so i added this and its working now, but I don't understand why when I right click and say execute stored procedure then select the null check boxes why it wouldn't default.  I guess checking null sends 'NULL' to the proc and not DBNull?

```
if @cacheStatus is null
begin
    set @cacheStatus ='notReady'
end
```

Comment: Any chance you can provide a sample of how the SP is called?

Comment: Your syntax looks good.  Check the value you're passing to @cachStatus.  (i.e., make sure you're not passing one).

Comment: Im calling it from entity frameworks (from a WCF service) and in management studio same behavior both places not defaulting the value

Comment: forget the `IF`, just use: `SET @cacheStatus = ISNULL(@cacheStatus,'notReady')`.  you can use a `SELECT @cacheStatus = ISNULL(@cacheStatus,'notReady'), @Xyz = ISNULL(@Xyz,'abc'), ...` to do multiple

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you sure that you aren't sending null in as the value for that parameter? The default is only used if you do not send that parameter in at all.

@JNK suggests a workaround like this if you have this issue:

```
IF @Cachestatus IS NULL SET @cachestatus = 'NotReady'
```

Comment: +1 - workaround would be to add `IF @Cachestatus IS NULL SET @cachestatus = 'NotReady'`

Comment: @JNk add that as a separate answer as it really is probably what should be accepted if this is indeed his problem.

Comment: @HL - I wouldn't have gotten to it without you pointing out passing `NULL` so no biggie.  Add a line to your answer for it.

Answer (score 3):

Call it like this:

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[PCS_DocumentCacheInsert]
    @sessionId = N'asdfssa',
    @mrn = N'asdf',
    @fromDate = NULL,
    @toDate = NULL,
    @aggregate = NULL,
    @author = N'author',
    @datePerformed = NULL,
    @docId = N'id',
    @encounterId = NULL,
    @facility = NULL,
    @level = NULL,
    @orderedByAuthor = NULL,
    @resultAuthor = NULL,
    @resultCode = NULL,
    @resultId = NULL,
    @resultName = NULL,
    @status = NULL,
    @subType = NULL,
    @type = NULL,
    @security = NULL,
    @serviceGroup = NULL,
    @witmurNum = NULL,
    @deptId = NULL,
    @deptText = NULL,
    @cacheCreateTS = NULL,
    --@cacheStatus = NULL,
    @cacheUpdateTS = NULL
```

You can't pass `@cacheStatus` if you want the default to get used.

Answer (score 2):

Another option that hasn't been mentioned yet is to use the keyword "DEFAULT" rather than passing a NULL value.

So when calling the SP the code would be:

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[PCS_DocumentCacheInsert]
    @sessionId = N'asdfssa',
    @mrn = N'asdf',
    @fromDate = NULL,
    ...  Just got rid of some lines to focus on the param in question - see DEFAULT below
    @cacheCreateTS = NULL,
    @cacheStatus = DEFAULT,
    @cacheUpdateTS = NULL
```