# Create temp table from provided variable column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, temp-tables

I want to create a temporary table, in which the columns will be those which I provide as parameter, separated by a delimiter.

For example, if the column names are: id, name, address..the respective table should contain the same amount and header names of the columns. Similarly, next time the column number and names could vary.

Any help in this regard?

Comment: How will the datatypes of the columns be identified?

Comment: Can't you switch from a temptable to a standard one ?

Comment: @EdHarper simple varchar would suffice for now.

Comment: @mCasamento I just need a table for a while which I could use to join other tables when I have the necessary data

Comment: This is a bad idea. You should reconsider your design. If the list of potential column names is limited, consider creating a temp table of a fixed schema and leaving some of the columns with `NULL` values.

Comment: @EdHarper I have more than 50 columns in my table, out of which only few get updated, I pass the updated data in xml format to sp, and the columns that get updated. Constructing a new table with all the columns is a bad idea what I think..any thoughts?

Comment: You can create a table variable with 50 columns in it .I don't think there is any wrong with this approach.Rather creating a dynamic temp table which i think wont work as you need to create global temp tables more over the complication increases as you are creating using dynamic  query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GenerateTempTable 
@tableName as nvarchar(max),
@Col1 as nvarchar(255),
@Col2 as nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql='CREATE TABLE #'+ @tableName  + '
         ('+ @col1+ ' nvarchar(255),'+
          @col2 + ' nvarchar(255)
         )'

-- Select @sql   Check the DDL 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql,
N'@tableName nvarchar(max),@Col1 nvarchar(255),@Col2 nvarchar(255)',
@tableName = @tableName,@Col1=@Col1,@Col2=@Col2 


END
```

The problem with the above query is temp table is created with the dynamic  block query therefore it cannot be accessed after the block . In order to access the table outside the scope then you need to create `global temp table ##`

Edit :- 
An example with Global Temp Tables and static table name

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GenerateTable 
@Col1 as nvarchar(255),
@Col2 as nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

If object_id('tempdb..##TempTable') is not null 
Drop table ##TempTable

set @sql='CREATE TABLE ##TempTable 
        ('+ @col1+ ' nvarchar(255),'+
        @col2 + ' nvarchar(255)
        )'

-- Select @sql   Check the DDL 

 EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql,
 N'@Col1 nvarchar(255),@Col2 nvarchar(255)',
 @Col1=@Col1,@Col2=@Col2 

 END
```

To execute the SP the sql is :-

```
 Declare @tableName varchar(max),
 @Col1 varchar(70),
 @Col2 varchar(70)

 Exec GenerateTable @col1='ColA',@Col2='ColB'
```

Edit 2:-

If you are sure that the number of parameters wont exceed x values ( Say 5) .Then you can create 5 default parameter .Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162752/default-parameter-values-in-sql-server-2008-stored-procedure) link for further  details.

Comment: Thank you very much, but here I see you are setting hard-coded columns i.e. Col1 and Col2, I want something like @Columns='Name,Address,Email'...any help?

Comment: When you execute the SP you will pass the column names .Kindly refer my updated answer

Comment: Your method limits me to only pass 2 columns, I want a table with dynamic number of columns somehow, in which I can pass the column names as parameter to the sp..

Comment: Number of Parameters cannot be dynamic .When you create a SP you have to specify the parameters .

Answer (score 0):

Could you not build a table out of a distinct list from wherever these "Dynamic Field Names" live... Then push that in as a string list... Like... I built a table with colors then got a field of names and now am going to push it into a string that can be used to build out the table headers... no limit to quantity...

```
SELECT @Fields = coalesce(@Fields + ',', '') +  convert(varchar(50),[name])
                FROM #TempCols
                WHERE column_id > 1
                ORDER BY column_id
```

Where Column_ID is just a Windowed ROW_Number...

I don't agree with the notion of its not possible ever. There is always a way, we may not see it now but there is always a method that can be nested or abused to bend any rule to what we need.